# $\phi:A\to B$, $F:C^B \to C^A$. $F(f)=f\circ\phi$. prove that if $\phi$ is injective, then F is surjective

Tags: functions, proof-verification, proof-writing

prove: let there be $\phi:A\to B$, $F:C^B \to C^A$. $F(f)=f\circ\phi$. prove that if $\phi$ is injective, then F is surjective.

I did something but from some reason I haven't used the $\phi$ so probably I did something wrong, would appreciate your notes.

this is what I did:

- we have to prove F is surjective, then we have to prove: $\forall g\in C^A \exists f\in C^B (F(f)=g)$
- From definition of F, we can call g to be $f\circ \phi$
- then, $F(f)=g=f\circ \phi$
- Let's notice that $f\circ \phi$ is indeed in Range(F)
- $\phi:A\to B$, $f:B\to C$, then $f\circ \phi:A\to C$

Thus, we found that $f\circ \phi$ is the element that exists in Range(F) for every f in Dom(F). Q.E.D (???)

Comment: You don't "call $g$ to be $f \circ \phi$"; you need to *define* $f$ in terms of $g$. You didn't actually prove anything, only restated what you wanted to prove.

Comment: @A.P. yes, that's what I thought.. I wondered how to use F to get to this g, but from some reason couldn't see that. that's why I did such a ridiculous thing. thanks

Comment: For a slightly different way of phrasing it, proving 'for all $g$ there exists an $f$ that meets condition X' (generally) means that you have to come up with a procedure where someone hands you a $g$ and you provide them an appropriate $f$ that satisfies condition X; it's almost a kind of game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g:A \to C$. We want to show that there exists $f:B \to C$ such that $f \circ \phi = g$. But $\phi$ is injective, and so it admits a left inverse $\psi:B \to A$, i.e., any function that chooses the unique preimage by $\phi$ of any element in $\operatorname{im}\phi$ and maps every other element of $B$ arbitrarily. Then we can take $f = g \circ \psi$, and for this choice we have $$f \circ \phi = g \circ \psi \circ \phi = g \circ \mathit{id}_A = g$$ as required.